# Microsoft Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, entity-framework, .net-3.5

I'm not sure if this question is appropriate for SO, but I'm sure a few people here have been through it:

I'm trying to follow the MVC tutorials on the ASP.NET website and there's a point at which it has you add an ADO.NET entity to the project, but for some reason, it doesn't appear on the dialog for adding a new item. I've got SP1 for .NET 3.5 installed, so I have no idea why it isn't showing up. Anyone know of something else I need to install or tick for it to show up?

Thanks

Comment: Good question. This really stumps people trying to familiarize themselves with the Entity Framework.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Entity Data Source appears on the Toolbox, in the Data section.

Here's some helpful information from [an MSDN blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/adonet/archive/2008/05/14/can-t-find-the-entity-data-source.aspx) for people who can't see the item in the Toolbox:

**Can't find the Entity Data Source?**

If you upgrade the RTM version of Visual Studio 2008 with SP1, the EntityDataSource control doesn't appear in the Data group of the Web project Toolbox by default. To add the control to the Toolbox:

- ·Open Visual Studio
- ·Open or create a    Web Application
  or Project.
- ·Make sure the Toolbox tool window is visible.
- ·Right click on the Toolbox, in the Data group and click on the "Choose Items…"  option.
- ·Wait for    the "Choose Toolbox
  Items"  window to    appear.
- ·Scroll down in the list of components under the ".NET Framework 
  Components"  tab until you find
  "EntityDataSource"
- ·Ensure the    checkbox is marked
  next to the    EntityDataSource
  component and click    on the OK
  button.

If you cannot see “EntityDataSource” in the list, you may need to add the assembly manually. To do that, click on the “Browse” button on the “Choose Toolbox Items” window. Then browse for the System.Web.Entity.dll under “C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\v3.5” or the equivalent folder in your configuration.

Answer (score 0):

You need the Visual Studio Team System 2008 Database Edition GDR.

http://blogs.msdn.com/gertd/archive/2008/11/25/visual-studio-team-system-2008-database-edition-gdr-rtm.aspx